Is Spring Web Socket Buffer Size Limit per connection
I'm working on a project where we are evaluating how much data load a spring service will potentially handle via web socket and how much buffer size should be set.
I understand when the web socket buffer comes into play and how to increase it. What I want to understand is: by increasing it, does that mean you increase the buffer size limit per client connection or is it a global web socket configuration for the particular spring service.
registry.setSendBufferSizeLimit(sendBufferSizeLimit)


As declared in the documentation: Configure the maximum amount of data to buffer when sending messages to a WebSocket session where a websocket session is a client connection.
Resource: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/WebSocketTransportRegistration.html
